# RxJava combine publishsubject with timeout

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to be able to subscribe to publishsubject and wait for result, but no longer than 1 minute.

The problem is that if I do

```
publishsubject.timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).subscribe({result -> ... }, {error -> ... } )
```

I always get error even if before that I successfully get result. How to properly implement this approach?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: TimeoutException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely get the timeout exception because `timeout` requires your source keeps producing items or completes within the specified time window. Thus, if you just signal one `onNext` to the `PublishSubject`and never more, you'll get a timeout due to lack of a second `onNext` call.

So if you want one item, use `take` (before or after `timeout`):

```
publishsubject
   .timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .take(1)
   .subscribe(result -> { /* ... */ }, error -> { /* ... */ } )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the exemple below I show how `timeout` works. For each emission, a new timeout is started and if a new item arrives before the timeout has ran the timeout is restated, otherwise an exception is thrown.

In the exemple, we can see 1, 2, 3 printing at console and it finish by a timeout exception because thE 4th item isn't here within the 200 milliseconds after the 3.

As I said in the comment below, you can avoid this if you know when you can terminate `publishSubject`. For exemple using `take`, `takeUntil` or calling `publishSubject.onComplete()` just after the 3rd item.

```java
    @Test
    public void timeout() throws InterruptedException {
        PublishSubject<Object> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        Observable<Object> timeout = publishSubject.timeout(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        timeout
                .subscribe(
                        e -> System.out.println(e),
                        error -> System.out.println("ERROR: " + error),
                        () -> System.out.println("complete")
                );

        sleep(50);
        publishSubject.onNext(1);
        sleep(150);
        publishSubject.onNext(2);
        sleep(199);
        publishSubject.onNext(3);
        sleep(201);
        publishSubject.onNext(4);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: It seems that even if I don't get success before 1 minute runs out I will never get timeout exception after one minute, or no?

Comment: you will not get a timeout, you want it ?

Comment: I want it if I don't get any success response during one minute. What I don't want is getting same timeout after I got a sucessful result.

Comment: you want this timeout for the first emission or for all ?

Comment: I want this timeout for all emissions. Every subscriber is supposed to get only one result and then unsubscribe.

Comment: The problem with timeout is the last item, how to tell the observable to stop the timeout ? Can you control it ?